# C# Multithreading CPU usage 100%

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, cpu-usage

My application is a asp.net web service. There is a one more windows service ruining in the same server and trigger the web-service by specified intervals.

So in each web-service call, in side the web server, it create a new thread and start to do the task that web service suppose to do.

Some times, this started thread could not finish the assigned task, before next web service call comes. So the next web-service call create a same kind of a new thread and assign new task to the new thread.

So if I check the server in busy situations, Sometime there are 20+ parallel threads ruining.

Every thing works fine. But server (windows 2003 sp2) looks not responding some times. So I check the CPU performance in the Task Manager and it shows 100% when the web-service start to work. even if there are only 1,2 threads same thing happens.

I feel something wrong. Am i doing something conceptually wrong. Appreciate some advice.

**Edit**

```
public class EmailPrinter : System.Web.Services.WebService

  public void webServiceMethod()
  {
      Thread email_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.downloadEmails));
      email_thread.Start();
  }   

  private void downloadEmails(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
    EmailService.init(); 
    EmailService.ReceiveEmail();
  }

}
```

Comment: Well, obviously you should not start another of those threads if the previous one has not finished executing yet. Postpone the thread execution until either the first one completes, or to the next scheduled start, at which point you would again make sure the previous one has completed executing. What you have discovered is typically called "convoying".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: that's not necessarily "obvious," depending on what the threads are doing. That said, it *is* obvious that there's a problem with either the threading method in use, or (more likely) with the code being run. I think we'd need to see the code to make any judgement.

Comment: I would start by ensuring the service only fires up one thread. This can be done in a number of ways (adding a private boolean field, _isWorking, using locks...). Log start and end to windows event log. Also, log start and end in the web service.

Comment: Since he mentions that he can see the 20+ threads himself, I thought it would be rather obvious that he cannot do it the way he's doing it.

Comment: I would start from trying to understand why only 1,2 threads are so CPU consuming, rather than limiting number of threads. It is only workaround. @Nayana Adassuriya have you tried to reproduce this on develpoment machine? You should try to profile this web service.

Comment: You need to remember that ASP already uses a pool of threads, so spawning new threads whether via thread pool or directly should always be done with caution, so you'd be better off looking to make your services async.

Comment: Not sure how anyone can make a comment here without an understanding of what the nature of these web service apis is? What their purpose is? What processing they trigger? What subsequent IO do they trigger? etc etc 20+ web service threads does not neccesarily mean 100% CPU utilisation... Is there a spin wait somewhere strangling the CPU? Too many questions... not enough detail

Comment: Hi all thank you very much for the ideas given. But unfortunately this  according to the requirement, this web service should be multithread. As I think multi threading is not the issue here. I guess. I'm doing something conceptually wrong. There are no any waiting in the threads. all threads are mutually exclusive and running isolated to each.

Comment: @Konrad Kokosa: Actually same result in the development computer also. I added source code to the question. you may help to check is there anything wrong creating the thread.

Comment: @daveL: purpose of this thread is print the attachment send through email. web service uses some 3rd party libs too. each thread connect to the email server and download the next email and print the attached files. no any waiting in the whole program. because each thread not wait for anything. so those can straight execute without affecting each other.

Comment: IIS is already calling each HTTP request on a different thread.  What is the point of you spinning up an additional thread?